# Does google data studio run query on bigquery while editing a report or using a report?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I made a report using the google data studio in which the data source is connected via bigquery. If I apply a filter on the report, I can see a query executed with those filter conditions in my bigquery 'Query History'. The data consumed by those queries will also add up to my bill, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everytime you change anything in a report (apply filter, interact with a chart, click refresh, etc) a new query is sent to BigQuery.

So the answer is **yes**, you pay for all queries sent to BigQuery.

You just don't pay for [BigQuery cached data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results).  So if DataStudio runs exactly the same query twice (supposing several users opening the dashboard and selecting the same filters), you'll be only charged once per each 24h timeframe.

Comment: And what if I add the data source via google sheet? Where does the calculation happen in that case?

Comment: If you connect DataStudio directly to a Google Sheet, there's nothing to charge (totally free). However, Google Sheets have its limitations (https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603) and they aren't fast as BigQuery (I would use them only for small amount of data or for data that I want to change often). If you use DataStudio->BigQuery->Sheets, you'll be charged by BigQuery. If you blend a BigQuery data source with Google Sheets data source, the part that belongs to BigQuery will be charged.